# SQL version of Python's itertools.combinations()

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, permutation

I am trying to replicate a Python function in SQL but I'm having trouble thinking about it in terms of tables and not loops/iteration.

```
import itertools
rangeStart = 1
rangeEnd = 20
rangeStep = 2
outputSize = 3

lst = range(rangeStart, rangeEnd, rangeStep)

list = list(itertools.combinations(lst, outputSize))
print(len(list))
```

How could I replicate in SQL the output of the above python code while still allowing for the inputs (to be able to tie to input fields in a User Interface)?

To be specific, the output should be permutations, not combinations. I am basically trying to have some inputs from the GUI, where they input the range (i.e. 0,20), the type of values (even, odd, or all), and the length of each tuple in the output. The output is a list of tuples that are sorted, so (1,2,3) is good, (2,3,1) or (1,3,2) is not good. The tuples are also increasing in value from left to right, so (2,4,6) is good, but (6,4,2) is not. The values in the tuple are also unique, so (4,4,6) is not good.

Comment: If the output should be permutations, then you want the eqivalent of `itertools.permutations`, not `itertools.combinations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive cte to generate odd numbers from 1 through 20 and then a series of `cross join`s.

```
with t(val) as (select 1 union all select val+2 from t where val<19)
select * 
from t t1
cross join t t2 
cross join t t3
where t1.val<t2.val and t2.val<t3.val
```

This produces the tuples in the list you currently have in the form of rows.

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/HKWM12679)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!